# Magento - Displaying the Sum price of all products

Tags: php, magento, sum

Okay, I am running Magento 1.7 and have been asked by my boss to have a bar at the top of our site showing the total number of items in stock and the total value of said stock.

So far, I've figured out the total number of items part.  I am not very good with PHP, so it's been a lot of trial and error.

Here is what my code looks like so far [UPDATED: has a filter to exclude out of stock products]:

```
    <?php  
    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
->joinField(
    'qty',
    'cataloginventory/stock_item',
    'qty',
    'product_id=entity_id',
    '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
    'left'
)
->addAttributeToFilter('qty', array('eq' <= 0));
    $_coreHelper = $this->helper('core');


    $sum = 0; 

        foreach ($collection as $product){ 
    $sum += $product->getPrice();
    }
?>

As of today our inventory consists of <span style="color: black; font-size:16px; font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: 400; border: 1px solid black; padding: 0px 2px 0px 2px;"><?php echo $collection->count(); ?></span> items with a total value of <span style="color: black; font-size:16px; font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: 400; border: 1px solid black; padding: 0px 2px 0px 2px;"><?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($sum); ?></span>
```

The sum section obviously doesn't work.

Can anyone give me a few pointers on how to accomplish this.  I'd assume that you would use a loop to load all of the products prices and then a sum to add them all together and display the total, but getting there correctly is proving a problem for me.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
but you'll have all item, in stock or not, enable or not...

Comment: Can't I add a filter under that to get rid of the out of stock items?  I've seen others do similar before.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can like this :

```
<?php $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('status','1');
$sum = 0;
$count = 0;
foreach ($collection as $_product) {
    $stock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product)->getQty();
    if ($stock>=1) {
         $sum+=$_product->getPrice()*$stock;
         $count+=$stock;
    }
}
echo "You have $count items for a total value of ".Mage::helper('core')->currency($sum);
```

Comment: Unfortunately that causes my main page to display nothing.  I'm getting "[18-Feb-2013 15:09:10] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_IF in /home1/melvynan/public_html/app/design/frontend/default/fly/template/catalog/category/stocktotal.phtml on line 6" in my error log.

Comment: Now I'm getting [18-Feb-2013 16:02:24] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /home1/melvynan/public_html/app/design/frontend/default/fly/template/catalog/category/cat_images.phtml on line 8

Answer (score 0):

I had some issues with dagfr's answer above, the getPrice() failed to return any values when executed on the admin dashboard,

Adding:

```
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('price');
```

Allowed me to then access the price via

```
$_product['price']
```